# Python - Visualizing data in a diagram

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, diagram, dendrogram

I have a data with two columns: Product and Category. See below for an example of the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Category': ['Text', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4', 'Text', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4'],
                   'Value': [80, 10, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 0]})
```

I would like to visualize this data in a diagram:

[image: desired_viz]

Here the "Total" is the total value of the entire data frame, "A" & "B" boxes are the total value for each product, and then the values for each product & category are in the right-most box.

I'm not very familiar with the viz packages available in Python. Is there a package that exists that does these types of visualizations.

Comment: You will need a combination of a calculation lib such as pandas (although extracting values from a dictionary should be an easy task), and an imaging lib. Check out: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [graphviz](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). But you need to extract your own blocks/nodes

Example:

```
from graphviz import Graph

g = Graph()
g.attr(rankdir='RL')

T = df['Value'].sum()
g.node('1', 'Total = ' + str(T), shape='square')

A = df.loc[df.Product == 'A', ['Category', 'Value']].to_string(index=False)
g.node('2', A, shape='square')

B = df.loc[df.Product == 'B', ['Category', 'Value']].to_string(index=False)
g.node('3', B, shape='square')

g.edges(['21', '31'])

g.render(view=True)
```

[image: data diagram python graphviz]